# How do you call call the operation that takes all possible sums of two elements from two vectors?

Tags: matrices, terminology, matrix-calculus

Take two vectors $a\equiv (a_1,...a_n)$ and $b\equiv (b_1,...,b_m)$. Is there any name and symbol for denoting the vector that lists all possible sums of one element of $a$ and one element of $b$? That is,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1+b_1\\
a_2+b_1\\
\vdots\\
a_n+b_m\\
\vdots\\
a_1+b_m\\
a_2+b_m\\
\vdots\\
a_n+b_1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: This operation would be much more natural on sets than on vectors, since there's no canonical ordering on the sums. On sets it's simply the sumset.

Comment: $(E_m\otimes a) + (b\otimes E_n)$

Comment: What are $E_m$ and $E_n$?

Comment: You can also write Exodd's answer using vectorization, i.e $\,{\rm vec}\!\left({\large\tt1}_ab^T + a{\large\tt1}_b^T\right)\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on Exodd's comment. Define $E_k$ as the $k$-dimensional vector with all components equal to 1. Then take the sum of the [outer products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) $(a\otimes E_m) + (E_n\otimes b)$ which is the $n \times m$ matrix $A_{ij} = a_i + b_j$. This is the transpose of Exodd's answer in the comments.

**Update:** As pointed out by Exodd, replace the Kronenecker product for the outer product in order to get a column vector.

Comment: uhm, actually by $\otimes$ I meant the Kronecker product

Comment: Thanks. Clarified.